# simplest way to implement datepicker in angular2?

Tags: typescript, datepicker, angular2-forms

I am new to angular2 typescript. I am trying to implement datepicker. I tried many but either I was mistaking in implementation or those were outdated.

My seed project doesn't have @NgModule.

Comment: If you're stuck on NgModule, then don't try implementing a date picker, because that's a very hard task. Learn the basics of Angular, start with angular-cli, and use, for example ng-bootstrap which provides reusable components such as a datepicker. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

Comment: If your project does not have an app.module.ts and you don't have a NgModule inside of this file than your app is outdated and doing it by angular is not an option, just try to implement a html css datepicker example https://codepen.io/maheshambure21/pen/VYJQYG